# Give an example of cochain map which is bijective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I am looking for a injective cochain map $\psi: C^*\rightarrow D^*$ such that the map $\Psi^i$ from $C^i$ to $D^i$ is injective, but the map $\psi^*$ from  $H^i(C^*)$ to $H^i(D^*)$ is not injective for any $i\geq0$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider any nonzero module $M$ and the following complexes : $C = \dots \to 0\to 0\to M \to 0\to \dots$ and $D= \dots \to 0\to M\to M \to 0\to \dots$, the only nontrivial map being the identity.

with the (co)chain map that is $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}0 @>>> 0 @>>> M @>>>0\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0@>>> M @>>> M @>>> 0\end{CD}$$
the only nontrivial map being again the identity. Then this is of course injective on the (co)chain level, but not on (co)homology, because $H^1(C)= M\neq 0$ and $H^1(D) = 0$

There is only one degree in cohomology on which this map is noninjective, if you want it to be injective on *no* degree in cohomology (as you asked), you can just shift this example at various degrees and take direct sums.

Comment: Thank you, can you give me another cochain map {phi}  for example, with these conditions like in a question above, but with bijiction  instead of injection?

Comment: Well no of course I can't : if it's a bijection then it's an isomorphism of complexes, and so it induces an isomorphism on (co)homology

Comment: Ok, in the example above, M is a manifold ?

Comment: What ? No it would make no sense for $M$ to be a manifold